# OnHandMeshUpdated() not triggered in Mixed Reality Toolkit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mrtk

I'm working on a Mixed Reality app in Unity.
I'm trying to update my own hand mesh according to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/input/hand-tracking?view=mrtkunity-2021-05#hand-mesh-prefab

```
public void OnHandMeshUpdated(InputEventData<HandMeshInfo> eventData)
{
    print("Hand mesh update!");
    if (eventData.Handedness == myHandedness)
    {
        myMesh.vertices = eventData.InputData.vertices;
        myMesh.normals = eventData.InputData.normals;
        myMesh.triangles = eventData.InputData.triangles;

        if (eventData.InputData.uvs != null && eventData.InputData.uvs.Length > 0)
        {
            myMesh.uv = eventData.InputData.uvs;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the method OnHandMeshUpdated(InputEventData eventData) never triggers. I use Holographic Remoting. I made sure I set the Hand Mesh Visualization Modes to "Everything" in MRTK -> Articulated Hand Tracking.
[MRTK Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltINZ.png)

What am I missing? How can I animate my own hand mesh?

Unity: 2020.3.26f1

MRTK: 2.7.3

Comment: Hi! Please attach the code, otherwise it's hard to say exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

check if you registered for global input events.
Maybe this link will provide some information.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/input-events?view=mrtkunity-2022-05

I tried Global input registration example in this link and it worked.